# Get a UIView’s bounds relative to the window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, bounds, cgrect

I have a few `UIButton` instances inside a `UIView`, which in turn is inside the main `UIView` of the app. What I’m trying to get is a `CGRect` of one of the buttons’ frames, relative to the window.

So, for instance, if my inner view is at `50, 50` in relation to the main view, then the button is at `10, 10` inside that, I’d want to return `60, 60`.

Is there an easy way to do that, without having to keep track of parent views and add them up, etc.?

Comment: - (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view;

- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view;

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a rough example of how I’d use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIView *parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
UIView *child = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[parent addSubview:child];
[self.view addSubview:parent];
NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect([self.view convertRect:child.frame fromView:child.superview]));
```

Result in log:

```
{{60, 60}, {10, 10}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a rect to a different view's coordinate system using `-[UIView convertRect:toView]` and `-[UIView convertRect:fromView:]`.

So, if you have a reference to your outermost view (perhaps if you're using a navigation controller, that might be the outmost view):

```
UIView *outerView = self.navigationController.view;
UIView *innerView = self.myButton;

CGRect buttonRect = [self.view convertRect:self.innerView.frame toView:outerView];
```

There are also equivalent `convertPoint:` methods. It's then really just a case of working out which views you want to convert from / to.

Comment: This is giving me some really strange results. The button in question is at `{162, 0}` in its superview, and that superview is at `{0, 355}` in the main view. However, it’s giving me `{324, 291}` as the output of `convertRect`. Why might this be?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Are you sure you're passing the right superview into `convertRect`/`convertPoint`?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. It’s button, inside button view, inside main view, and I’m calling `CGPoint centerOfButtonInSuperview = [button convertPoint:button.center toView:self.view];`

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you use `button.origin` instead of `button.center`?

Answer (score 0):

Use below function.

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view;

CGPoint pt = [button convertPoint:CGPointMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y) toView:yourWindow];
```